# Convert a directory of Kodak PhotoCD images into TIFF format

Tags: linux, imagemagick, batch-processing, image-conversion

I have a directory full of Kodak Photo CD files (with file extension .pcd) and I was disappointed (and alarmed) to find that neither GIMP nor digiKam could open this old image format. Time to move these old files to a format with better software support.

How can a TIFF image file be produced from each Photo CD file using the Linux command line and ImageMagick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked perfectly for me on a Bash command line:

```
for file in *.pcd;\
  do convert $file[6] -colorspace RGB "`basename $file .pcd`.tiff";\
done
```

(This can all be typed onto a single line without the backslashes, but I've used the Bash backslash escape to break this long line into three, to make it easier to read on this page.)

The `for file in *.pcd` statement selects all of the files in the current directory which have the file extension ".pcd". The `do` statement executes a command-line instruction, in this case a call to the ImageMagick `convert` tool, replacing `$file` with the name of each file selected. And the loop is closed with the `done` statement.

The `basename $file .pcd` function simply returns the name of the current file without the directory path and without the file extension, allowing us to replace ".pcd" with a ".tiff" extension. This also tells ImageMagick to use TIFF as the output image format. (ImageMagick will allow other image formats.)

In the parameters to the `convert` tool, the filename suffix of `[6]` is necessary to tell ImageMagick to select the largest size of image stored in the PhotoCD file, that is 6144 pixels on its longest side and 4096 pixels on its shortest. A [Kodak Photo CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_CD) file contains a scanned image in six different sizes, and you can choose the output image size produced by `convert` by changing the value you use for this filename suffix:

- Suffix `[1]` produces an image 192 by 128 ("Base/16")
- Suffix `[2]` produces an image 384 by 256 ("Base/4")
- Suffix `[3]` produces an image 768 by 512 ("Base")
- Suffix `[4]` produces an image 1536 by 1024 ("4 Base")
- Suffix `[5]` produces an image 3072 by 2048 ("16 Base")
- Suffix `[6]` produces an image 6144 by 4096 ("64 Base")
- Omitting the suffix has the same effect as giving suffix `[3]`.

The parameter `-colorspace RGB` seems to be necessary to get the colours to look right, otherwise the resulting image is badly washed out.

Answer (score 1):

I just converted old PhotoCD with ImageMagick, so some additional hints:

1. The mogrify tool will do the thing without the loop:

   d:\ImageMagick\magick mogrify -format PNG -colorspace RGB *.pcd[5]
2. Normal PhotoCDs just support [5], the [6] was only on the pro-version.
3. ImageMagick needs the files to be copied before, the CD is read-only.